# Web interface where I can draw objects and export PostGIS insert statements

Tags: web-apps, database, maps, postgresql, gis

I am looking for an application that will allow me to draw a box or polygon on a map and then export the definition in a PostGIS database so that I can insert it into my own database.

Currently, my approach is to open Google Earth, find the latitude, longitude, and elevation points that define the box on a map, and then construct a string that can be inserted into a database (similar to [this approach using R](https://rpubs.com/dlebauer/postgis_geometry)).

Is there a web application that provides both the GUI front end for drawing polygons and how these polygons are defined as PostGIS geometry data types?

I assume QGIS or ArcGIS have this functionality, but I am looking for something much simpler.

Comment: I would recommend [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/index.html) but it seems your asking for a web application so I'm commenting instead of answering.

Comment: You could also try [uMap](http://umap.openstreetmap.fr/en/), it gives you a web interface for drawing shapes on a map. It can export in GeoJSON, GPX or KML, maybe one of those could be converted to PostGIS?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a solution that works in a web interface (to allow edits in a browser to be added to your server based database) you should look at GIS server software that provides [Transactional Web Feature Service capabilities (WFS-T)](http://docs.opengeospatial.org/is/09-025r2/09-025r2.html).

For example you could use [GeoServer](http://geoserver.org), or [TinyOWS](http://mapserver.org/uk/tinyows/serverinstallation.html)

You can use WFS-T services in conjunction with desktop GIS software like [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org), or you can use them with web clients, such as those built in OpenLayers